# Ajax iFrame reload using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, iframe, reload

I have two tabs each tab which the default shown is "update entry" and each has an iFrame inside.

```
<div id="tabContainer">
<div class="tabWrapper">
    <a class=active id=iEntrylist onClick="return showMenu('Entrylist','iEntrylist')" href="javascript:">Entry List</a>
    <a class=nonactive id=iAddList onClick="return showMenu('AddList','iAddList')" href="javascript:">Open Deals</a>
</div>
</div>

<!-- LIST SECTION -->
<div class="tabDiv" id="Entrylist">
 <iframe src="../include/EntryList.php" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" id="_iframe2" width="100%"></iframe>
</div>

<!-- ADD LIST SECTION -->
<div class="tabDiv" id="AddList" style="display: none;">
<iframe src="../include/AddList.php" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" id="_iframe2" width="100%"></iframe>
</div>
```

Now from update entry tab once the update button click the iframe1 which contain the list of entries will be reloaded. I have my codes below but it doesn't work. The update is working but reload the iFrame is not.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".updateBTN").click(function () {
        var data = $(this).attr('id');
        //alert (data);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../update.php",
            data: {
                'id': data
            }
        }).done(function (msg) {
            $("#notification").html(msg);
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                parent.document.getElementById('iframe1').location.reload()
            }, 500);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try put in the end of click the return false. Some like this:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".updateBTN").click(function () {
            var data = $(this).attr('id');
            //alert (data);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "../update.php",
                data: {
                    'id': data
                }
            }).done(function (msg) {
                $("#notification").html(msg);
                window.setTimeout(function () {
                    parent.document.getElementById('iframe1').location.reload()
                }, 500);
            });

            return false;
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `contentWindow` to select the iFrame window.

```
parent.document.getElementById('iframe1').contentWindow.location.reload()
```

Comment: Are you getting your updated values set in a database? This may be a backend issue. When you refresh everything manually, are the values set from the update?

Comment: i'm getting the update successfully. Yes I have to refresh the page manually to see the update.

Comment: Are you getting any JavaScript errors in your console? I would add semicolons after `javascript:` in your href tags.

Comment: Your ids are the same for both `iframes`. Change them to unique ids.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$('#iframe1',window.parent.document).attr('src',$('#iframe1',window.parent.document).attr('src'));
```